# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework 6 abnormal behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that takes some time to execute (~60 seconds) that I call using EF like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "myStoredProcedure @param1",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1)
);
```

The stored procedure consists of two parts:

1. inserting a new row into table `tblSomeTable` and afterwards
2. calculating some info from multiple tables that **do not** include `tblSomeTable`.

The second operation is the time consuming one. When I execute this stored procedure from SSMS I can see that a new row is added to `tblSomeTable` **before** the procedure finishes executing which is a normal behavior, but, when I run the same exact procedure using the above code then a new row in `tblSomeTable` is added only when the procedure finishes executing.

Also while the procedure is running, I cannot query `tblSomeTable` at all (both from EF and SSMS), from what I assume that there is a lock placed on `tblSomeTable` until the procedure finishes. Why is this happening?

This is on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Does your ExecuteSqlCommand work successfully? You only want to know what you can see the data into tblSomeTable  while running the command? RIght?

Comment: Yes it does, and yes I only want to see the row in the tblSomeTable. (before the procedure finishes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

It is not an abnormal behavior. You can't see the data inserted into `tblSomeTable` because when you call `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` a new SQL Server transaction is created. This is what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) says:

> If there isn't an existing local or ambient transaction a new transaction will be used to execute the command.

And the default isolation level used for the transaction by EF is the highest which is **Serializable**. It means that any SQL query that is executed outside of the transaction can't see any data that is currently inserted into `tblSomeTable` when the transaction is not committed. The data is invisible to your query executed in SSMS when your `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` doesn't finish its work.

You can change the isolation level but I don't recommend it if the only purpose of that is to check what your stored procedure is doing when calling `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

**Edit** after **@David Browne - Microsoft** comment:

The default isolation level of EF is **READ COMMITTED** and not **SERIALIZABLE** as I said above. The inability to read data that is not committed is still apply.

Definition from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql):

> Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but
>   not committed by other transactions. This prevents dirty reads. Data
>   can be changed by other transactions between individual statements
>   within the current transaction, resulting in nonrepeatable reads or
>   phantom data. This option is the SQL Server default.

Comment: Note EF does not use Serializable transactions by default.  Just normal Read Committed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#What%20EF%20does%20by%20default) :

> Starting with EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present

So you won't see any changes in SSMS until it ends.